# Unable to find a specification for `UMConstantsInterface` depended upon by `EXLocalAuthentication`

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, podfile, react-native-unimodules

I'm trying to update my react native version to 0.66.4. I tried to follow the helper tool (https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.61.5&to=0.66.4) but it didn't worked.

This is my package.json:

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "^0.66.4",

"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "git-commit-msg-linter": "^2.4.4",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.6",
    "metro": "0.64.0",
    "metro-config": "0.64.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  }
```

and the podfile content:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'EjectApp' do

  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/React/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'React-callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/callinvoker"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'RCT-Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec'

  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
  pod 'React-perflogger', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/reactperflogger'
  pod 'React-runtimeexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/runtimeexecutor'

  use_native_modules!
  use_unimodules!
  target 'EjectAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end
  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()
  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

But when I run pod install I got the following error:

```
Unable to find a specification for `UMConstantsInterface` depended upon by `EXLocalAuthentication`
```

I also tried removing node_modules, cleaning the cache, but nothing worked.

Could someone help me with this?
Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

running into same error in recently updated RN project. We use expo-local-authentication (which is now replaced by expo package but has not yet been updated in our project). This could be related, or not.